# Returning objects from controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to return objects from controller. 
My code looks like this:

score.component.js:

```
angular.module('score').component('score',{
    templateUrl : 'app/score/score.template.html',
    controller : ScoreController
});


function ScoreController() {

    var f = function(){

    return [{
        name: "john",
        totalscore: 13,
        gamesPlayed: 14
    },
    {   name: "andrew",
        totalscore: 1,
        gamesPlayed: 2
    }
    ];
    }
}
```

score.template.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">
    {{a.name}}{{a.totalscore}}{{a.gamesPlayed}}
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: So, in your controller, what do you want to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller is defined by constructor function. Constructor function already has an object associated with it (`this`), returning another object is antipattern, unless this is the desired behaviour.

It should be something like

```
function ScoreController() {
  this.f = [...];
}
```